# packages only for development on android, to not take up much space when installing unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I do not have much storage, I need information about the packages that I have to install to develop on Android, it happens that to download new versions of the unit I download all the packages and that is a lot of storage space. is there any solution or workaround?

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First you can download unity and android `sdk` separately as well and then give a path to android `sdk` in `Unity`. Meaning they can exist independently.

But to answer your question. Even if you download everything from scratch you are not bound to keep different copies of android `sdk`. You can delete the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all better read this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html 
Android Build Support for sure and SDK, NDK better installed with Unity are required